# Why are these console.log statements not working? Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to test something here.

I am using electron and javascript. I am trying to load a profile into the page when a user selects it. None of my console log statements are showing in the console, however when the user makes the "profileSelect" change event, the values are loaded correctly. The reason I am testing this is because I am trying to add an addition to this file, checking a checkbox (it's not working either).

```
profileSelect.change(function(event) {
    //If the value isn't null
    console.log('yo')
    if (profileSelect.val() == '') {
        clearBilling();
    } else {
        ipcRenderer.once(profileSelect.val() + 'profileData', function(event, data) {
            //Return card to style it was first added like
            console.log('sshi')
            //This allows us to parse the data on profile save
            const cardParse = String(data.card.number).match(/.{3,4}/g).join(' ')
            const dateParse = String(data.card.month) + ' / ' + String(data.card.year);
            profileName.val(profileSelect.val());
            billingFirstName.val(data.billing.firstName);
            billingLastName.val(data.billing.lastName);
            billingAddress1.val(data.billing.address1);
            billingAddress2.val(data.billing.address2);
            billingCity.val(data.billing.city);
            billingState.val(data.billing.state);
            billingZipcode.val(data.billing.zipcode);
            billingCountry.val(data.billing.country);
            billingPhone.val(data.billing.phone);
            billingEmail.val(data.email);
            shippingFirstName.val(data.shipping.firstName);
            shippingLastName.val(data.shipping.lastName);
            shippingAddress1.val(data.shipping.address1);
            shippingAddress2.val(data.shipping.address2);
            shippingCity.val(data.shipping.city);
            shippingState.val(data.shipping.state);
            shippingZipcode.val(data.shipping.zipcode);
            shippingCountry.val(data.shipping.country);
            shippingPhone.val(data.shipping.phone);
            cardName.val(data.card.name);
            cardNumber.val(cardParse);
            cardCVV.val(data.card.code);
            cardExpire.val(dateParse);
        })
        //Send the selected profile
        ipcRenderer.send('requestProfile', profileSelect.val())
    }
})
```

Why aren't the console log statements logging? Thanks for any input :)

Comment: Which console are you looking at? Last time I worked with electron I remember that there was the command console window showing, as well as the developer tools for the "browser" view itself. Different parts of the app wrote to their appropriate console. Are you checking both?

Comment: Look at the source inspector inside your electron window and step through code to see what is running

Comment: @BryanGrezeszak Yes, I work frequently with Electron. It should be showing in the dev tools console. It doesn't show in either

Comment: Does your app have a webview? If so, are you looking at the devtools console from `window.webContents.openDevTools()` or `...webview.openDevTools()`? Make sure you're not accidentally looking at the wrong dev tools. Second, make sure your devtools doesn't have any filters on it.

Answer (score 6):

Electron has 2 processes, and hence 2 consoles. The 2 processes are main and renderer, main being a node.js process, renderer being a browser process.

Main process `console.log` would be shown in the terminal (if running in dev) or in the browser console window if in the renderer process.

You seem to be logging from the renderer process as per the `ipcRenderer` statements.

The renderer console can be shown via the standard chrome devtools shortcut (as its running a chrome instance) (usually F12)

You won't be able to see any console statements from renderer in main, or main in renderer.

Comment: Read the question comments. OP already covered this possibility before you answered.